# Python - group/merge dictionaries based on key/values identity

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, key

I have a list containing many dictionaries with same keys but different values.

What I would like to do is to group/merge dictionaries based on the values of some of the keys.
It's probably faster to show an example rather than trying to explain:

```
[{'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 3, 'C2': 15},
 {'zone': 'B', 'weekday': 2, 'hour': 6,  'C1': 5, 'C2': 27},
 {'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 7, 'C2': 12},
 {'zone': 'C', 'weekday': 5, 'hour': 8,  'C1': 2, 'C2': 13}]
```

So, what I want to achieve is merging the first and third dictionary, since they have the same "zone", "hour" and "weekday", summing the values in C1 and C2:

```
[{'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 10, 'C2': 27},
 {'zone': 'B', 'weekday': 2, 'hour': 6,  'C1': 5, 'C2': 27},
 {'zone': 'C', 'weekday': 5, 'hour': 8,  'C1': 2, 'C2': 13}]
```

Any help here? :) I've been struggling with this for a couple of days, I've got a bad unscalable solution, but I'm sure there is something far more pythonic that I could put in place.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you might be using the wrong data structure for this. Have you considered something like Pandas?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - why aren't dictionaries suitable?

Comment: @wwii It’s not necessarily that dictionaries are unsuitable, rather, in my opinion, the shape of the data looks tabular. If you’re performing any more complex operations, then something powerful like Pandas would be quite beneficial.

Comment: For example, I think this particular operation could be done in Pandas like this: `df.groupby(['zone', 'weekday', 'hour']).agg('sum')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort then group by the relevant keys; iterate over the groups and create new dictionaries with summed values.

```
import operator
import itertools

keys = operator.itemgetter('zone','weekday','hour')
c1_c2 = operator.itemgetter('C1','C2')

# data is your list of dicts
data.sort(key=keys)
grouped = itertools.groupby(data,keys)

new_data = []
for (zone,weekday,hour),g in grouped:
    c1,c2 = 0,0
    for d in g:
        c1 += d['C1']
        c2 += d['C2']
    new_data.append({'zone':zone,'weekday':weekday,
                     'hour':hour,'C1':c1,'C2':c2})
```

---

That last loop could also be written as:

```
for (zone,weekday,hour),g in grouped:
    cees = map(c1_c2,g)
    c1,c2 = map(sum,zip(*cees))
    new_data.append({'zone':zone,'weekday':weekday,
                     'hour':hour,'C1':c1,'C2':c2})
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my lame attempt and faster than the others.

Comment: It was a hard choice to pick the right answer here, because the 3 solutions are all perfectly valid. Despite this one is probably the slowest (as @RishiG demonstrated), I think it fits my specific needs better than the others, so I'm gonna vote this one! But thanks everyone for the contribution!

Comment: @ffede - it was just my version that was slowest.  This one is cleaned up and faster than the others.  I didn't update my answer after this one showed up.

Comment: I added an update to my answer that reflects this solution.

Answer (score 3):

By using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) you can merge them in linear time.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

for d in dictionaries:
        res[(d['zone'],d['weekday'],d['hour'])]['C1']+= d['C1']
        res[(d['zone'],d['weekday'],d['hour'])]['C2']+= d['C2']
```

The drawback is that you need another pass to have the output as you've defined it.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and written a slightly longer solution, making use of nametuples as keys of the dictionary:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

zones = [{'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 3, 'C2': 15},
 {'zone': 'B', 'weekday': 2, 'hour': 6,  'C1': 5, 'C2': 27},
 {'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 7, 'C2': 12},
 {'zone': 'C', 'weekday': 5, 'hour': 8,  'C1': 2, 'C2': 13}]

ZoneTime = namedtuple("ZoneTime", ["zone", "weekday", "hour"])
results = dict()

for zone in zones:
    zone_time = ZoneTime(zone['zone'], zone['weekday'], zone['hour'])
    if zone_time in results:
        results[zone_time]['C1'] += zone['C1']
        results[zone_time]['C2'] += zone['C2']
    else:
        results[zone_time] = {'C1': zone['C1'], 'C2': zone['C2']}


print(results)
```

This uses a namedtuple of (zone, weekday, hour) as the key to each dictionary. Then it's fairly trivial to either add to it if it already exists within `results`, or create a new entry in the dictionary.

You can definitely make this shorter and "smarter", but it may become less readable.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: Run Time Comparison

My original answer (see below) was not a good one, but I think I had a useful contribution by doing a little bit of run time analysis on the other answers so I've edited that portion and put it at the top.  Here I include the three other solutions, along with the required transformations to produce the desired output.  For completeness I also include a version using `pandas`, which assumes that the user is working with a `DataFrame` (transforming from list of dicts to data frame and back was not even close to worth it).  Comparison times vary a little depending on the random data generated, but these are fairly representative:

```py
>>> run_timer(100)
Times with 100 values
    ...with defaultdict: 0.1496697600000516
    ...with namedtuple: 0.14976404899994122
    ...with groupby: 0.0690777249999428
    ...with pandas: 3.3165711250001095
>>> run_timer(1000)
Times with 1000 values
    ...with defaultdict: 1.267153091999944
    ...with namedtuple: 0.9605341750000207
    ...with groupby: 0.6634409229998255
    ...with pandas: 3.5146895360001054
>>> run_timer(10000)
Times with 10000 values
    ...with defaultdict: 9.194478484000001
    ...with namedtuple: 9.157486462000179
    ...with groupby: 5.18553969300001
    ...with pandas: 4.704001281000046
>>> run_timer(100000)
Times with 100000 values
    ...with defaultdict: 59.644778522000024
    ...with namedtuple: 89.26688319799996
    ...with groupby: 93.3517027989999
    ...with pandas: 14.495209061999958
```

Take aways:

- working with pandas data frames pays off big time for large datasets

  - NOTE: I do *not* include conversion between list of dicts and data frame, which is definitely significant
- otherwise the accepted solution (by wwii) wins for small to medium datasets, but for very large ones it may be the slowest
- changing the sizes of the groups (e.g., by decreasing the number of zones) has a huge effect which is not examined here

Here is the script I used to generate the above.

```py
import random
import pandas

from timeit import timeit

from functools import partial

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict


def with_pandas(df):
    return df.groupby(['zone', 'weekday', 'hour']).agg(sum).reset_index()


def with_groupby(data):
    keys = itemgetter('zone', 'weekday', 'hour')

    # data is your list of dicts
    data.sort(key=keys)
    grouped = groupby(data, keys)

    new_data = []
    for (zone, weekday, hour), g in grouped:
        c1, c2 = 0, 0
        for d in g:
            c1 += d['C1']
            c2 += d['C2']
        new_data.append({'zone': zone, 'weekday': weekday,
                         'hour': hour, 'C1': c1, 'C2': c2})

    return new_data


def with_namedtuple(zones):
    ZoneTime = namedtuple("ZoneTime", ["zone", "weekday", "hour"])
    results = dict()
    for zone in zones:
        zone_time = ZoneTime(zone['zone'], zone['weekday'], zone['hour'])
        if zone_time in results:
            results[zone_time]['C1'] += zone['C1']
            results[zone_time]['C2'] += zone['C2']
        else:
            results[zone_time] = {'C1': zone['C1'], 'C2': zone['C2']}
    return [
        {
            'zone': key[0],
            'weekday': key[1],
            'hour': key[2],
            **val
        }
        for key, val in results.items()
    ]


def with_defaultdict(dictionaries):
    res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for d in dictionaries:
        res[(d['zone'], d['weekday'], d['hour'])]['C1'] += d['C1']
        res[(d['zone'], d['weekday'], d['hour'])]['C2'] += d['C2']
    return [
        {
            'zone': key[0],
            'weekday': key[1],
            'hour': key[2],
            **val
        }
        for key, val in res.items()
    ]


def gen_random_vals(num):
    return [
        {
            'zone': random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
            'weekday': random.randint(1, 7),
            'hour': random.randint(0, 23),
            'C1': random.randint(1, 50),
            'C2': random.randint(1, 50),
        }
        for idx in range(num)
    ]


def run_timer(num_vals=1000, timeit_num=1000):
    vals = gen_random_vals(num_vals)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(vals)
    p_fmt = "\t...with %s: %s"
    times = {
        'defaultdict': timeit(stmt=partial(with_defaultdict, vals), number=timeit_num),
        'namedtuple': timeit(stmt=partial(with_namedtuple, vals), number=timeit_num),
        'groupby': timeit(stmt=partial(with_groupby, vals), number=timeit_num),
        'pandas': timeit(stmt=partial(with_pandas, df), number=timeit_num),
    }
    print("Times with %d values" % num_vals)
    for key, val in times.items():
        print(p_fmt % (key, val))
```

where

- `with_groupby` uses [the solution by wwii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59164340/2715819)
- `with_namedtuple` uses [the solution by Jose Salvatierra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162141/2715819)
- `with_defaultdict` uses [the solution by abc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162099/2715819)
- `with_pandas` uses the solution proposed by Alexander Cécile in comments

  - assumes data is already in a `DataFrame` and produces a `DataFrame` as result

#### Original answer:

Just for fun, here's a completely different approach using `groupby`.  Granted, it's not the prettiest, but it should be fairly quick.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

vals = [
    {'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 3, 'C2': 15},
    {'zone': 'B', 'weekday': 2, 'hour': 6,  'C1': 5, 'C2': 27},
    {'zone': 'A', 'weekday': 1, 'hour': 12,  'C1': 7, 'C2': 12},
    {'zone': 'C', 'weekday': 5, 'hour': 8,  'C1': 2, 'C2': 13}
]
ordered = sorted(
    [
        (
            (row['zone'], row['weekday'], row['hour']),
            row['C1'], row['C2']
        )
        for row in vals
    ]
)


def invert_columns(grp):
    return zip(*[g_row[1:] for g_row in grp])


merged = [
    {
        'zone': key[0],
        'weekday': key[1],
        'hour': key[2],
        **dict(
            zip(["C1", "C2"], [sum(col) for col in invert_columns(grp)])
        )
    }
    for key, grp in groupby(ordered, itemgetter(0))
]

pprint(merged)
```

which yields

```py
[{'C1': 10, 'C2': 27, 'hour': 12, 'weekday': 1, 'zone': 'A'},
 {'C1': 5, 'C2': 27, 'hour': 6, 'weekday': 2, 'zone': 'B'},
 {'C1': 2, 'C2': 13, 'hour': 8, 'weekday': 5, 'zone': 'C'}]
```